# Windows Server 2012 - Trace CPU Spike / Takeover

Tags: windows-server-2012, central-processing-unit

I have had a problem in the last few days where every 10-15 minutes, my entire server goes non-responsive, shutting out all TCP connections, for about 3 minutes.

I finally found that the connections shut out because all 16 cores spike to a solid, stable 100% CPU for the duration of those 3 minutes.

I am actively trying to find out what is maxing out the CPU, however, as everything on the server totally freezes (even in the console), I can't check fast enough to find out what it is.

This is obviously a big problem and I need to get it handled right away. Is there some way to log this CPU spike and distinguish it from the rest of the traffic?

Answer (score 1):

The only answer I can currently think of is a little bit hacky, but it might get you an answer.  First is capturing the process causing the issue.  Schedule something like this to run every minute in a command window:

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime
```

Or you could schedule it and change the command line to pipe it >> into a file.

That will give you the CPU usage of all running processes.  From there you could use a tool like ProcDump (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) to monitor the troublesome application and dump information about it when the CPU hits a certain percentage used.

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

Something to try:
In the event viewer do a save as on the logs and open them up on another machine so you'll have time to look at them. Do this by selecting the log you want to save and selecting actions - save as. If you save them as the default file format you can open them up in the event viewer on another machine. I think even a windows desktop. You can also save them as a .csv.

Instructions here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749339.aspx